# Is it possible to have a common repository for multiple pipeline jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 11 jobs running on the Jenkins master node, all of which have a very similar pipeline setup. For now I have integrated each job with its very own Jenkinsfile that specifies the stages within the job and all of them build just fine. But, wouldn't it be better to have a single repo that has some files (preferably a single Jenkinsfile and some libraries) required to run all the jobs that have similar pipeline structure with a few changes that can be taken care of with a work around?

If there is a way to accomplish this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) to define common functionality. Your 11 Jenkinsfiles can then be as small as only a single call to the function implementing the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using a `Shared Library`, you can create a groovy file with common functionality and call its methods via `load()`.
[Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#code-load-code-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script)
and [example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/tree/master/pipeline-examples/load-from-file). This is an easier approach, but in the future with the increasing complexity of pipelines, this may impose some limitations.